AWS ALB CSRF invalid
I've setup a PHP application that has EasyCSRF token enabled to secure the form submissions.
I've also enabled stickiness in the ALB however after generating the token, and then submitting the form, the token is invalidated immediately. The token is generated successfully so unsure what the issue is.
It's suggested to enable cross-zone in the target groups which I've enabled too but still not retaining the valid token.
What other information could I provide to help trouble shoot the issue?
